# Add node to rep sets from command line bypassing mongo shell

Tags: python, mongodb

I am automation the addition of a node to mongo replicated sets.

```
$ mongo IP.Of.Server.One
> rs.initiate();
> rs.add("IP.Of.Server.Two");
> rs.add("IP.Of.Server.Three");
> rs.status();
```

I have a python script that when a new node is booted, I will add that ip address to an already existing node in the set by using paramiko to ssh into an existing node.

How can  I automate from the command line with out having to go into the mongo shell.  I Could use pexpect but prefer a one liner by bassing and shell use.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--eval` command line option to pass the `rs.add()` JavaScript command to the primary on your replica set.  If you wrap the `rs.add()` call in `printjson()` you will also get a result echoed to stdout that your Python script can parse.

So assuming a primary of `node1.replset` you could add a new node `node4.replset` with:

```
mongo --eval "printjson(rs.add('node4.replset:27017'))" node1.replset:27017
```

Comment: why port 27020 on the second node when on a separate server?  can I use 27017 for all servers?

Comment: You can use 27017 for all servers; updated the example.  I originally tested the command line on my localhost, so used a different port :).